# how does appending objects to lists in python work?

Tags: python, twisted

```
a = [1,2,3]
b =[]
b.append(a)
print a
print b[0]
a = [2,3,4,5]
print a
print b[0]
```

here b[0] and a are not the same when the script ends

---

In this example from twisted, we can access protocols by pushing them to lists in the factory.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MultiEcho(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.echoers.append(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        for echoer in self.factory.echoers:
            echoer.transport.write(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.echoers.remove(self)


class MultiEchoFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.echoers = []

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MultiEcho(self)

reactor.listenTCP(4321, MultiEchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

So if anything changes in the different protocol for every respective tcp connection, how does factory.echoers point to this modified protocol objects?

Comment: Useful read: [Drastically Improve Your Python: Understanding Python's Execution Model](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've misunderstood your first example. `a` and `b` are not the same because you've simply rebound `a` to a different value. If instead of doing that, you'd modified the contents of `a` - for example, by doing `a[0] = 3` then you would see that `b[0][0]` would also be 3.